# PHP web scoket : stop working while sending large data

Tags: php, sockets, websocket

I had done PHP websoket; server and client from **https://github.com/Flynsarmy/PHPWebSocket-Chat**

There are many clients connected to server, **while php web socket server sending large amount of data (i.e 1,000,000 characters) to one client, at that time another client cant able to connected PHP web socket server until all large data send by server.**

Is there any thing that sever send large data to client without waiting to another client ( asynchronism like )? My purpose is that **PHP socket server should not stop to other clients while they want to connect with web socket server.**

Comment: No, there isn't a way to handle multiple concurrent messages from different users using that server without rewriting the core logic.

Comment: Also, that FlynsArmy websocket server is implementing an old, insecure draft version of the websocket standard. For the sake of you and your users, find a server that implements RFC 6455 ( https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455 ), also known as Version 13.

Comment: @Ghedipunk is there a way that we can create another php file to send message with client id, and that php file will run "nohup" command. So, we haven't have to wait to send concurrent messages ?

Comment: **Short answer: It's not worth it.** Long answer: The second (and third, and fourth, etc.,) script would need to listen on a different port, and there would have to be some sort of more-complicated-than-necessary interprocess communication going on to get chat messages from one user through its listening WS process, to all of the other WS processes on your server, then out to all of the other connected users. By that time, it's a major rewrite of the core logic, which means it would be easier to, and you might as well, rewrite the server to handle large messages gracefully.

Comment: @Ghedipunk instead of socket can we use xmpp server with openfire? If yes then how php will interact with xmpp on every incoming and outgoing message.

Comment: Possibly, and no clue.  (I'm not the one to ask, and such questions really don't have a place in the comment section of a StackOverflow question, anyways. -- A better place would be in a chat room with developers devoted to the platforms you're investigating.)