# PHP Return Long String is not Usable as String

Tags: php, arrays, string, return, return-value

I am having a for loop which is iterating through a large array `$result`. Every array item `$row` is used to generate a new line of string `$line`. This string is concatenated into `$str`. To preserve memory, I am using `unset($result[$i])` to clear every array item that has been processed in the original array. This looks like this:

```
$resultcount = count($result);
for($i=0; $i<$resultcount; ++$i){
   $row = $result[$i];

   $line = do_something($row);
   $str.= '<tr><td>'.$line.'</td></tr>';
   unset($result[$i]);
}

return $str;
```

This (more or less exotic piece of code) works unless the string exceeds a length of approx. 1'000'000 characters. In this case the return value is just empty. This is highly irritating because:

1. The calculation effort (in this example `do_something()`) is not a problem. By using `echo count($result).' - '.strlen($str)."\n"` I can see that the loop finishes properly. There is no web server or php error shown.
2. The `memory_limit` is also not a problem. I am working with more data on other parts of the application.

It appears that the problem lies in `return $str` itself. If I am using `return substr($str, 0, 980000)` then it just works fine. Further debugging shows that the string gets tainted as soon as it reaches the length of 999'775 bytes.

I can't put longer return value string into another string variable. But I am able to do a `strlen()` to get a proper result (1310307). So the return value string has a total length of 1'310'307 bytes. But I can't use them properly as a string.

Where does this limitation come from and how may I circumvent it?

Comment: Don't send HTML from backend. Only send data in JSON format and make tables on frontend using javascript. This way request is fulfilled faster too since there will be less number of bytes to send over the network to the client browser.

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31655069/php-web-scoket-stop-working-while-sending-large-data

Comment: Apply the pagination or filter for the result array with query or using array_filter [http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php] that improves processing speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it took me two and a half year to figure this out ;(

Rarst was right: It was not a problem of the function compiling and delivering the string. Later in the process I was using `preg_replace()` to do some further replacements. This function is not able to handle long strings. This could be fixed by using `ini_set('pcre.backtrack_limit', 99999999999)` beforehand as mentioned in [How to do preg_replace on a long string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791015/how-to-do-preg-replace-on-a-long-string)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to describe return value in contradicting way:

> In this case the return value is just empty.

but

> But I am able to do a strlen() to get a proper result (1310307). So the return value string has a total length of 1'310'307 bytes.

Something can't be empty and have length at the same time?

I have tested returning a string that long and it works fine for me. Returning larger and larger strings works to a point memory limit is exceeded, which triggers explicit Fatal Error.

On a technical side strings can be *much* larger than million characters:

> Note: As of PHP 7.0.0, there are no particular restrictions regarding the length of a string on 64-bit builds. On 32-bit builds and in earlier versions, a string can be as large as up to 2GB (2147483647 bytes maximum)
>   http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

I suspect that the failing operation has to do with how you *use* the result rather than return from the function.